# Are rvalues always constant?

Tags: c++

When `int i = 5;`

```
int j = i;
```

Will rvalue `i` in this expression be a constant when evaluating the result?

I'm asking this question because in my copy constructor its argument requires a `const`

Comment: “Requires a `const`”: If it accepts a `const A&`, you can also pass it some `A&`, since the cast from non-const to const happens implicitly.

Comment: You should add the code of "your copy constructor" and explain what you mean by "requires a `const`". This will help in getting an answer to your actual doubt, rather than an answer to a possibly mislead question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a common misunderstanding around the lvalue/rvalue terms. They do not refer to variables, but rather to expressions. An expression can yield either an lvalue or an rvalue, and that can be either const or non-const.

In particular, in your code the expression `i` on the right hand side of the definition `int j = i;` is an lvalue expression, not an rvalue. For the purpose of assignment there is an lvalue to rvalue conversion and then that is assigned to the newly declared variable.

Cont-ness is an orthogonal concept --in most cases-- and relates to whether you can or cannot mutate the object that you are dealing with.

```
int f();
int& g();
const int& h();
const int k();

int main() {
  f();         // non-const rvalue expression
  g();         // non-const lvalue expression
  h();         // const lvalue expression
  k();         // const rvalue expression
  f() = 5;     // error, cannot assign to an rvalue
  g() = 5;     // correct, can modify a non-const lvalue
  h() = 5;     // error, cannot modify a constant lvalue
}
```

Other examples require the use of user defined types:

```
struct test {
   void foo() { x = 5; }
   void bar() const;
   int x;
};
test f();
const test g();
int main() {
   f().foo();      // f() is a non-const rvalue, 
                   // but you can call a method on the resulting object
   g().foo();      // g() is a const rvalue, 
                   // you cannot call a mutating member function
   g().bar();      // but you can call a const member function
}
```

Comment: Hi, why can't i compile the first example? thanks. I tried commenting the error statements but still doesn't compile.

Comment: @user12321: You can probably compile but not *link* as the functions are not defined (is the error something like *undefined symbol...*?). Add a function body like `{ static int x = 10; return x; }` to each one of the functions, comment those lines that are marked as error and try again. (The `static` is there only to make sure that the variable is still alive after returning from the versions that return references)

Answer (score 3):

In C++, rvalues of built-in type cannot be const or non-const. It just doesn't make sense. There can be, however, const and non-const rvalues  of class types.

An rvalue is just the VALUE (not the object/variable). What would you understand with "non-constant value" ?!

Comment: @Armen: I'm not @downvoter, but... You said "In C++, rvalues of built-in type cannot be const or non-const." An rvalue **must** be either const or non-const. In the OPs example, i is the rvalue and is **non-const**. If i was declared `const int i=5;` then when used as an rvalue, the rvalue is **const**.

Comment: @qbert: wrong :) C++ Standard 3.10.9 states Class rvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class rvalues always have cv-unqualified types. Rvalues shall always have complete types or the void type; in addition to these types, lvalues can also have incomplete
types.

Comment: @qbert220: also see 4.1/1-2: "If T is a non-class type, the type of the rvalue is the cv-unqualified version of T ... The value contained in the object indicated by the lvalue is the rvalue result". So to be precise `i` is *not* the rvalue. `i` is an lvalue expression, which is *converted* to rvalue. The resulting rvalue is 5, and has type `int`. It would of course be misleading to describe this as *non-const* `int`, since there's nothing you can do with a non-class rvalue for which it makes any difference whether it's const or non-const. Hence Armen's description as "neither".

Comment: You can more or less think of lvalue-rvalue conversion as "loading the value out of memory", although that says slightly more about the way the compiler and the emitted code work, than is actually nailed down by the standard. So the rvalue is the result of loading the current value of `i` (perhaps into a register), it isn't `i` itself.

Comment: @Armen, @Steve - thanks for the explanation. I understand it now - `i` is not an rvalue. The result of evaluating the expression `i` is the rvalue.